# PDF text extraction issue - font/capitalization inconsistencies

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, adobe-indesign, text-extraction, truetype

I am trying to extract text from a pdf book and continue to run an issue where sections of copied text fail to retain the proper capitalization properties when pasted into a text document. I have rights to reproduce the book and also have a license to use all necessary fonts. At first I thought that the issue was caused by the fonts not being embedded, but I checked and all fonts appear to be subset embedded. Within the pdf there are over 100 fonts used which have one of the following properties:

TrueType Encoding: Ansi
TrueType (CID) Encoding: Identity-H
Type 1 (CID) Encoding: Identity-H
Type 1 Encoding: Custom

The languages within the book include English, German, Spanish and Italian. In German capitalization is absolutely critical. It tends to lose the uppercase properties more than the lower.

An example of the error would be: WELD -> weld

I am really at a loss at what to do here. I have requested that the owner of the book embed the fonts which he has done as subsets but the problem continues. I have tried saving the pdf file as a postscript and then ran it through distiller which correctly much of the problem, but in some cases resulted in text being replaced with different characters or numbers showing up as skulls. I understand that CID fonts might be contributing to the issue, but I have come across instance where a non CID font had the same result.

What could be causing this issue? Is it that the fonts are subset versus fully embedded? Is there a better way to save the native file (InDesign) to a pdf that will allow for better font extraction? Does it have to do with non-unicode fonts and if so is there an alternative that does not require the owner to select different fonts?

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately you neither say which tool you use for text extraction nor do you provide a sample PDF to illustrate the issue. Generally errors in text extraction may be due to incomplete or wrong information in fonts. But there is also the case of a caps/smallcaps font which can be implemented by only embedding capital letters and then displaying them at different sizes. Each embedded letter only has one ToUnicode value,  though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed funny. The sample PDF provided by the OP indeed visibly contains upper case characters, some of them in upper case only lines, some in mixed case lines, which by Adobe Reader are extracted as lower case characters.

You wonder

> What could be causing this issue?

As an example how that happens let's look at `Pelle Più bella`

In the page content that phrase actually looks like the visual representation in capital letters:

```
/T1_0 1 Tf
-0.025 Tc 12 0 0 12 379.5354 554.8809 Tm
(PELLE PI\331 BELLA)Tj
```

Looking at the used font **T1_0** (a DIN-Bold subset) we see that it claims to use **WinAnsiEncoding** which would also indicate an interpretation of those character codes in the page stream as capital letters

But the font also has a **ToUnicode** mapping, and this mapping maps

```
<41> <0061> — 'A' → a
<42> <0062> — 'B' → b
<43> <0043> — 'C' → C
<44> <0044> — 'D' → D
<45> <0065> — 'E' → e
<49> <0069> — 'I' → i
<4C> <006C> — 'L' → l
<4D> <004D> — 'M' → M
<4E> <006E> — 'N' → n
<50> <0050> — 'P' → P
<52> <0072> — 'R' → r
<53> <0053> — 'S' → S
<54> <0074> — 'T' → t
<D9> <00F9> — 'Ù' → ù
```

(I only extracted the mappings from character codes which in WinAnsiEncoding represent capital letters.)

> Is there a better way to save the native file (InDesign) to a pdf that will allow for better font extraction?

Sorry, I'm not really into InDesign. But that software being from Adobe I would be surprised if that was a bug in InDesign or its export to PDF. Could it instead be that there are some information in the InDesign file which tag *PELLE PIÙ BELLA* as *Pelle Più bella* which InDesign then in the PDF export translates into this ToUnicode mapping?

> Does it have to do with non-unicode fonts and if so is there an alternative that does not require the owner to select different fonts?

In case of your sample document there are three fonts, all of them with an **Encoding** entry **WinAnsiEncoding,** all of them being an embedded subset, but only two have such funny **ToUnicode** mappings, DIN-Medium and DIN-Bold, while Helvetica has no **ToUnicode** mapping. So it somehow is font related. How exactly I cannot say.

**A workaround** in case of your sample document would be to *remove* the **ToUnicode** mapping from the font dictionaries.

For example using Java and the iText library you can do that like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUT);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getXrefSize(); i++)
{
    PdfObject obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
    if (obj != null && obj.isDictionary())
    {
        PdfDictionary dic = (PdfDictionary) obj;
        if (PdfName.FONT.equals(dic.getAsName(PdfName.TYPE)))
        {
            dic.remove(PdfName.TOUNICODE);
        }
    }
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

After this manipulation Adobe Reader text extraction results in

```
PELLE PIÙ BELLA
```

This obviously only works in situations like the one in your sample document.

If in your other documents there is a mixture of fonts some of which require their respective **ToUnicode** map for text extraction while others are like the trouble fonts above, you might want to add some extra conditions to the Java code to only remove the map in the buggy font definitions.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful information. Do you have any advice on the best way to encode pdfs for font extraction? It seems like there are so many types of encoding. My understanding is the encoding is dependent on the type of font. Would a .ps file work better than a pdf? Would this allow for distiller to dictate how to encode the embedded fonts?

Comment: Also, what tool did you use to arrive at that information? I have been using a number of scripts but have not been able to gather the same information. I really appreciate your assistance with this one.

Comment: *any advice on the best way to encode pdfs for font extraction* - well, I would expect InDesign to properly export to PDF. Thus, you should first investigate what makes InDesign export those weird mappings. The tool I used is a PDF object browser, iText RUPS in my case. Obviously some knowledge on the PDF internals also is important.

Comment: Interesting fact that I just discovered. When a PDF is exported and the option to save as tagged is marked the text extracts correctly. When the tagging option is not marked, the problem continues. Any ideas why? I have read the spec sheets off of Adobe website but cannot understand why it would effect proper encoding. I understand tagging to deal more with accessibility and flow.

Comment: Tagging information can include the clear text as it is intended, and that information by the Adobe Reader is considered more relevant than what it would extract from the page description and resource information. Thus, it does *not* have an effect on the encoding but renders it unimportant for text extraction.

Comment: MKL I have a couple theories on why this is occurring and would like to discuss with you further. Would you be willing to speak offline? If so email email me at 5386a8c4@opayq.com . I really appreciate all the assistance you have been able to provide.

Comment: I was able to perform some more research and notice that when the "Create Tagged PDF" is selected during export text appearnce properties that were applied in InDesign are retained. When it is not tagged the original unicode value is retained. One other item I found was that if an uppercase character is used within the doc and then the text properties are added the values are retained as seen with XYZ in the third example. MLK looking at these samples does that make sense? I have read PDF reference 1.7 which is a long read and want to make sure if tagging is the solution.

Comment: Here are the links:http://furzo.net/Sample_not_tagged.pdf http://furzo.net/Sample_tagged.pdf http://furzo.net/Sample_not_tagged_XYZ_cap

Comment: Question: Will simply exporting with the value "Create tagged PDF" improve text extraction? Is there any additional risk to the text content when tagging a PDF?

Comment: Analyzing your new samples I see that in case of "Create Tagged PDF" the **ToUnicode** map itself is correctly mapping capitals to capitals while without it doesn't. That seems weird, a "tagging" option should not influence the PDF export in such a way. *Additional risk*? I have no idea, and things being so weird here I don't dare to guess. *Other item* I assume that changing the text properties in the eyes of InDesign does not change what the writing originally was; but as each character appearance is exported but once, only the first interpretation is exported... Weird, weird, weird.

Answer (score 0):

No need to jump through PDF hoops. It isn't even a good text interchange format to begin with.

> Is there a better way to save the native file (InDesign) to a pdf that will allow for better font extraction?

Ask the file provider to make an RTF export. This will retain all used fonts and formatting.

Your WELD-weld problem might be because of the font (if it contains both upper- and lowercase mapped to the same glyphs), use of an OpenType feature such as All Capitals, or even something like a badly created text-only stream inside the PDF.