# PDFBox 2.0.7 ExtractText not working but 1.8.13 does and PDFReader as well

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

hopefully you have an idea of what is going wrong with extracting a text from PDF using pdfbox 2.0.7. The result is very strange:

Using 1.8.13, the command `java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.13.jar ExtractText -sort -nonSeq test.pdf` leads to

```
Deutsche Bank Privat- und Geschäftskunden AG

Bruttoertrag 43,80 USD 37,15 EUR
Kapitalertragsteuer (KESt) - 5,36 USD - 4,55 EUR
Solidaritätszuschlag auf KESt - 0,29 USD - 0,25 EUR
Umrechnungskurs USD zu EUR 1,1791000000
Gutschrift mit Wert 15.08.2017 32,35 EUR
```

Using 2.0.7, the command `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar ExtractText -sort test.pdf` leads to

```
aeutsche Bank mrivat- und deschäftskunden Ad

Bruttoertrag QPIUM rpa PTINR bro
hapitaäertragsteuer EhbptF - RIPS rpa - QIRR bro
poäidaritätszuschäag auf hbpt - MIOV rpa - MIOR bro
rmrechnungskurs rpa zu bro NINTVNMMMMMM
dutschrift mit tert NRKMUKOMNT POIPR bro
```

The debugger with `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar PDFDebugger test.pdf` shows the correct text in `Root/Pages/Kids/[1]/Contents/[1]` so somehow the text is read correctly but not exported correctly.

I have tried to compare the information shown in the two PDFDebugger applications but they seem rather identical to me (although I don't know where/what to look for exactly). Unfortunately, I cannot share the PDF document.

I would be happy for any kind of hint of how to solve or even only attack this problem as otherwise I cannot use the newer version of pdfbox. Thanks in advance for your time!

Here is a screenshot of the Font which is used in the document (extracted with 2.0.7). This is exactly the translation of the letters that apparently is not performed:

[image: font table from pdfbox PDFDebugger]

The entry ToUnicode says

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 Resource-CMap
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /AdHoc-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
68 beginbfchar
<0004> <0021>
<0009> <0026>
<000b> <0028>
<000c> <0029>
<000f> <002c>
<0010> <002d>
<0011> <002e>
<0012> <002f>
<0013> <0030>
<0014> <0031>
<0015> <0032>
<0016> <0033>
<0017> <0034>
<0018> <0035>
<0019> <0036>
<001a> <0037>
<001b> <0038>
<001c> <0039>
<001d> <003a>
<001e> <003b>
<0024> <0041>
<0025> <0042>
<0026> <0043>
<0027> <0044>
<0028> <0045>
<0029> <0046>
<002a> <0047>
<002b> <0048>
<002c> <0049>
<002e> <004b>
<0030> <004d>
<0031> <004e>
<0032> <004f>
<0033> <0050>
<0034> <0051>
<0035> <0052>
<0036> <0053>
<0037> <0054>
<0038> <0055>
<0039> <0056>
<003a> <0057>
<003d> <005a>
<0044> <0061>
<0045> <0062>
<0046> <0063>
<0047> <0064>
<0048> <0065>
<0049> <0066>
<004a> <0067>
<004b> <0068>
<004c> <0069>
<004d> <006a>
<004e> <006b>
<004f> <006c>
<0050> <006d>
<0051> <006e>
<0052> <006f>
<0053> <0070>
<0055> <0072>
<0056> <0073>
<0057> <0074>
<0058> <0075>
<0059> <0076>
<005a> <0077>
<005d> <007a>
<006c> <00e4>
<0081> <00fc>
<0089> <00df>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

The TextView of page 2 of PDF already shows the correct text, but then somehow these replacement tables that are shown above seem to incorrectly modify the text content before it is exported by pdfbox:

```
Root/Pages/Kids/[1]/Contents/[1]:
=================================
0 Tw
0 Tc
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 RG
BT
  /F1 10 Tf
  1 0 0 1 69.449 697.11 Tm
  (Wir) Tj
  1 0 0 1 87.199 697.11 Tm
  (\374berweisen) Tj
  1 0 0 1 141.099 697.11 Tm
  (den) Tj
  1 0 0 1 160.549 697.11 Tm
  (Betrag) Tj
  1 0 0 1 192.759 697.11 Tm
  (von) Tj
  1 0 0 1 211.649 697.11 Tm
  (32,35) Tj
  1 0 0 1 239.429 697.11 Tm
  (EUR) Tj
  1 0 0 1 263.299 697.11 Tm
  (auf) Tj
  1 0 0 1 279.959 697.11 Tm
  (Ihr) Tj
  1 0 0 1 294.389 697.11 Tm
  (Konto) Tj
  1 0 0 1 323.269 697.11 Tm
  (XXXXXXX) Tj
  1 0 0 1 364.959 697.11 Tm
  (XX) Tj
  1 0 0 1 376.079 697.11 Tm
  (.) Tj
  0 G
  0 g
ET
69.449 669.448 m
69.449 669.698 l
549.921 669.698 l
549.921 669.448 l
549.921 669.198 l
69.449 669.198 l
h
f
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 RG
BT
  /F1 6 Tf
  1 0 0 1 249.022 658.948 Tm
  (Kapitalertr\344ge) Tj
  1 0 0 1 288.016 658.948 Tm
  (sind) Tj
  1 0 0 1 300.682 658.948 Tm
  (einkommensteuerpflichtig!) Tj
  1 0 0 1 213.865 652.783 Tm
  (Diese) Tj
  1 0 0 1 230.863 652.783 Tm
  (Mitteilung) Tj
  1 0 0 1 258.187 652.783 Tm
  (wurde) Tj
  1 0 0 1 276.187 652.783 Tm
  (maschinell) Tj
  1 0 0 1 306.187 652.783 Tm
  (erstellt) Tj
  1 0 0 1 325.507 652.783 Tm
  (und) Tj
  1 0 0 1 337.177 652.783 Tm
  (wird) Tj
  1 0 0 1 349.837 652.783 Tm
  (nicht) Tj
  1 0 0 1 364.165 652.783 Tm
  (unterschrieben.) Tj
  0 G
  0 g
ET
q
  1 0 0 1 504.562 772.646 cm
  1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
  q
    0 Tw
    0 Tc
    45.36 0 0 45.36 0 0 cm
    /I0 Do
  Q
Q
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 RG
BT
  /F1 10.5 Tf
  1 0 0 1 552.756 23.464 Tm
  (2) Tj
  1 0 0 1 558.594 23.464 Tm
  (/) Tj
  1 0 0 1 561.503 23.464 Tm
  (2) Tj
ET
Q
q
0 0 m
0 841.89 l
595.276 841.89 l
595.276 0 l
h
0 0 m
595.276 0 l
595.276 841.89 l
0 841.89 l
h
W
n
Q
```

1.8.13 shows:

```
Wir überweisen den Betrag von 32,35 EUR auf Ihr Konto XXXXXXX XX.
Kapitalerträge sind einkommensteuerpflichtig!
Diese Mitteilung wurde maschinell erstellt und wird nicht unterschrieben.
2/2
```

2.0.7 shows:

```
tir überweisen den Betrag von POIPR bro auf fhr honto XXXXXXX XX
hapitaäerträge sind einkommensteuerpfäichtig!
aiese jitteiäung wurde maschineää ersteäät und wird nicht unterschriebenK
O/O
```

This is the file that you were asking for: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/214674449c23713ee481c5a8f529418320170827201941/b2bea6

Comment: You say you *cannot share the PDF document*. Without a sample document which allows observing the issues, though, no one can analyse the problem. As is I would assume the document contains incomplete information on the encoding or mapping to Unicode, so a text extractor can only guess, and how pdfbox guesses, may have changed.

Comment: What I find odd is that the older version of pdfbox is able to extract the text but the newer version is not. Don't you find that this is unexpected, @tilman-hausherr? And I cannot share the document because as you might have seen it is from a bank and contains confidential information, or is there a way to strip the PDF from this confidential information, @mkl? I was hoping that someone had some kind of idea of what to look at in the debugger, whether there was some kind of encoding problem or such that changed from version 1.8.13 to 2.0.7.

Comment: @stephanmunich https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression Re: the file, try Adobe Professional whether the personal info can be changed to XXXX or whatever. Be careful with "redaction" tools, some of these don't do this properly. Do a copy & paste of the text from Adobe Reader to be sure.

Comment: @stephanmunich what do you get currently when you copy & paste the text from Adobe Reader? Is it correct or incorrect?

Comment: @stephanmunich what would also be interesting is if you'd look at the font with PDFDebugger and add a screenshot... and in the wrong font, search for "ToUnicode" and post that content too.

Comment: I checked with the different `textStripper.setDropThreshold(2)` levels (2, 2.5, 3), they all produce the same result. On page two of the document, there is only very little information and just one line, may be I can share this with you but I have to ask first.

Comment: However, I have noticed something that might help: Some letters are decipehred correctly, others are always transalted incorrectly by the same offset. Capital letters (e.g. a "W" would be desired) is a small "t" (incorrect), that means, three letters off and small instead of capital. The same is true for "E" (would be correct) => "b" (shown), "U" (would be correct) = "r" (shown), other incorrect conversions are "l" (small L, would be correct) = "ä". Numbers are shown as capital letters instead of numbers.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr if I open the document with Adobe Reader and copy and paste the text, the text is copied correctly. I also edited the document with Adobe Professional, but it seems to change the file as well so that this does not reproduce the problem because the changed file can be read correctly by pdfbox.

Comment: Rendering has problems too, the Umlauts are incorrect. And the font has the "symbolic" flag set.

Comment: Related: [PDFBOX-4749](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4749)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information about the font in question in your PDF are *contradictory and partially broken*. Depending on how some software reacts to that it may or may not extract the text correctly.

---

On the one hand the font has an **Encoding** value **WinAnsiEncoding**. This is ok and matches what we see in the content stream, a one-byte encoding covering many of the ANSI codes.

On the other hand we have a **ToUnicode** map which implies that the underlying encoding is some two-byte encoding (it has a code space range `<0000> <ffff>`), and even if one ignores the two-byte nature, it has mappings which in particular map digit ANSI codes to uppercase letters, uppercase letter ANSI codes to other lowercase letters, and the lowercase 'l' ANSI code to the Unicode value of 'ä'.

When extracting text, PDFBox 2.0.x seems to follow the broken **ToUnicode** map (interpreting the two-byte codes in the tabel as one-byte codes, ignoring the upper 0) where possible (resulting in garbage) and else interpret the character code as ANSI (resulting in proper text). PDF 1.8.x seems to have ignored the **ToUnicode** map, and so does Adobe Reader.

---

Actually it looks like the **ToUnicode** map has been made for a font using **Identity-H** encoding.

---

If you are confronted with such a PDF and need to extract its text, you can pre-process it and remove the **ToUnicode** entries; thereafter text extraction should return proper text. E.g.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(SOURCE);

for (int pageNr = 0; pageNr < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNr++)
{
    PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNr);
    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
    removeToUnicodeMaps(resources);
}

PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

*([ExtractText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractText.java#L198) test method `testNoToUnicodeTest2`)*

using helper methods

```
void removeToUnicodeMaps(PDResources pdResources) throws IOException
{
    COSDictionary resources = pdResources.getCOSObject();

    COSDictionary fonts = asDictionary(resources, COSName.FONT);
    if (fonts != null)
    {
        for (COSBase object : fonts.getValues())
        {
            while (object instanceof COSObject)
                object = ((COSObject)object).getObject();
            if (object instanceof COSDictionary)
            {
                COSDictionary font = (COSDictionary)object;
                font.removeItem(COSName.TO_UNICODE);
            }
        }
    }

    for (COSName name : pdResources.getXObjectNames())
    {
        PDXObject xobject = pdResources.getXObject(name);
        if (xobject instanceof PDFormXObject)
        {
            PDResources xobjectPdResources = ((PDFormXObject)xobject).getResources();
            removeToUnicodeMaps(xobjectPdResources);
        }
    }
}

COSDictionary asDictionary(COSDictionary dictionary, COSName name)
{
    COSBase object = dictionary.getDictionaryObject(name);
    return object instanceof COSDictionary ? (COSDictionary) object : null;
}
```

*(from [ExtractText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractText.java#L219))*

You should execute this pre-processing as early as possible after loading the document to prevent the fonts including the wrong **ToUnicode** mappings to be read into the document font cache.

Comment: Thank you for these hints. If I understand correctly from the information shown by the PDFDebugger, the PDF is produced by XEP (http://www.renderx.com/reference.html). Since you seem to be an expert @mkl, do you know or can you see from that documentation whether XEP is known to produce a broken ToUnicode map? And how was pdfbox 1.8.x able to circumvent this broken ToUnicode map? Is it possible that pdfbox could somehow detect if a ToUnicode map is broken and based on that information automatically decide which encoding to use? Or do you have another suggestion of how to fix this issue?

Comment: The information are contradictory. Thus, a piece of software needs to decide which information to trust. Unfortunately, there are many PDFs out there with a completely incorrect **Encoding** value, too, so preferring the **Encoding** value is not a solution, either. You might want to analyse a representative collection of documents to find out whether XEP always produces PDFs with broken **ToUnicode** maps. If that is the case, you can process XEP PDFs by removing all **ToUnicode** maps.

Comment: Beware, though: probably not XEP is the culprit but instead some postprocessor manipulating XEP documents which simply does not put its name into the metadata...

Comment: OK, thank you, I think I understand that there is no general solution possible, what a pity. Do you by chance know how to force PDFBox 2.0.x to not use the embedded ToUnicode map? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @stephanmunich I'm not aware of a simple switch that tells PDFBox to do so. But you always can first traverse the font resources and remove the **ToUnicode** elements.

Comment: @stephanmunich I've added some code to my answer to illustrate how to remove the **ToUnicode** maps.

Comment: Great pointer and answer. For what it's worth, Deutsche Bank 2021 "Kontoauszug" still shows XEP as producer, still decodes incorrectly with stock PDFBox (I have 2.0.22 here currently) and *it does work* with your `removeToUnicodeMaps` trick. Thanks!!