# Extracting wrong character for space while using ExtractText command line tool

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Command used to extract file is `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar ExtractText -console DiffSzSpaceIssue.pdf`. Output for the same is.

```
This%is%one%
This%is%two%
This%is%three%
This%is%four%
```

Checked the pdf with PDFDebugger. I see the following entry for the troubled "%"

```
Code Glyph Name Unicode Character Glyph
37   1          %                 None
```

Can you please how to properly extract text in such cases when there are unicodes but the glyphs are not present? I'm expecting the below output, as that "%" character is never rendered in the pdf.

```
This is one
This is two
This is three
This is four
```

Input pdf file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4r9OFqWuTxWWtINUJuZ3IwVDA).

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting? What is a "troubled" `%`?  Most importantly, what is in `DiffSzSpaceIssue.pdf` and why is the output you are getting incorrect?  Did you examine the PDF file an an editor to see what it contains?

Comment: Hey @Jim, edited the question to be more clear. PDF looks fine as the character "%"(not sure where it came from) is never rendered by the pdf as it doesn't have a graphical equivalent mapped.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for the PDFBox support [users mailing list](https://pdfbox.apache.org/mailinglists.html) as there's a good chance it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison, I will email the mailing list. Just wanted to be sure if I was doing something wrong with usage flags etc.. before escalating.

Comment: Actually, asking on the support list should be your first choice.  "Escalating" would be asking here.

Comment: Noted @jimgarrison , thanks for looking!

Comment: @bulbus a sensible check in such situations usually is to try and copy&paste the text from adobe reader. I just did that (using adobe reader for android as I'm currently on a smart phone only), and there also are those '%'  characters.  Thus, one can be pretty sure that the issue is in the pdf, not in pdfbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently sometimes the Unicode mapping could be wrong in some pdfs and in such cases one needs to remove the Unicode mapping and re-try the extracting. This question clearly points out where the mapping is wrong. `%->None` (Unicode->Glyph)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922162/6935152

Comment: Haven't had the chance to try it. But will post if this doesn't work.